# how to get nested array data in jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, datatables

I have the following JSON data:

```
{
"00100": {
    "claim_id": "21",
    "reference_no": "00100",
    "distributor_name": "Standard Match",
    "group_name": "A",
    "month": "Jun2017",
    "grand_total": "268.532",
    "details": [
        {
            "claim_id": "65",
            "product_name": "Lucky Match Type 1",
            "price": "102.00",
            "quantity": "02",
            "net_amount": "179.52"
        },
        {
            "claim_id": "66",
            "product_name": "Lucky Match Type 2",
            "price": "101.15",
            "quantity": "01",
            "net_amount": "89.012"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I want to get this data in Jquery Datatables, but i want to out put like this showing in below image:

[image]

Comment: Please share your `HTML`, `JavaScript` code, till now whatever you tried.

Comment: @Shiladitya please take a look this https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html

Answer (score -2):

i guess you can't since jquery datatable will not work with table inside table.
Sorry if i am wrong.

please go through this for further reference 
https://datatables.net/blog/2011-06-19

May be you can.